# Spring Data projection works improperly on derived interface

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I found Spring Data (spring-data-jpa:1.11.4.RELEAE) projection, [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/#projections) , does not work properly on derived interface.

For

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7096149328600371740L;

    @Id
    @Column(length = 36)
    private String id;

    private String code;

    private String name;

    private Boolean deleted;

    //...
}

public interface FooRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo>{
       <T> List<T> findAllByDeletedIsFalse(Class<T> type);
}
```

Failed on derived interface. Error is cannot find property `text` ...

```
public interface IdText {
    String getId();

    String getText();
}

public interface IdTextFromIdName extends IdText{

    String getId();

    String getName();

    @Override
    default String getText() {
        return  getName();
    }
}

/// Failed.
List<IdTextFromIdName> foos = repo.findAllByDeletedIsFalse(IdTextFromIdName.class);

/// if getText() is annotated as  
///
///    @Value("#{target.name}") 
///    String getText();
///
/// previous repo call is failed too.
```

Pass

```
public interface IdTextFromIdName {

    String getId();

    String getName();

    default String getText() {
        return  getName();
    }
}

/// Pass
List<IdTextFromIdName> foos = repo.findAllByDeletedIsFalse(IdTextFromIdName.class);
```

The use case is, I want to get a common view of IdText across different entities.

```
List<IdText> idTexts = ...
```

Comment: I don't see any property `text` in the entity `Foo`. Could you please explain what do you mean?..

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/#projections

Comment: Why did you send this link? I know this doc.

Comment: The second root interface is worked, but the first derived interface is not.

Comment: It's because second projection has method `getName()` that related to property `name`.

Comment: Annotation `@Value` don't work on default interface methods...

Comment: I've improved sample code. Please see code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167863/discussion-between-raymond-and-cepr0).